# How to solve the recurrence relation

Tags: tag-removed

How to solve the recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n / 2)+ n
```

by recursion tree to get an asymptotic upper bound?

The height is n, but how to generalize the sum at each levels?

Comment: Hm, this looks like homework...

Comment: IMHO also off-topic.

Comment: Reported in the "to-close" thread on meta.  Fauzil, if you want a reference, go check Brassard&Bratley, or Cormen Leiserson Rivest & Stein.

Comment: Closing as homework. If this was incorrect, please explain on meta in the linked thread.

Comment: The tag is inappropriate but the subject matter...where wlse would one ask his kind of question (it's not solvable in 'closed form').

Comment: @Mitch: having no other place to ask about X doesn't mean that X is necessarily on-topic here. :)